# How do you use COLUMN_JSON with COLUMN_GET on dynamic columns in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

When I do the following query;

```
SELECT name, COLUMN_GET(attr, 'appearance' as char) as 'attributes' from items;
```

I see the 2 columns including the blob data with the weird formatting.

Is it possible to include the COLUMN_JSON function to format the data inside of the select query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to do this.

In the first part of the SELECT, is where you would do the COLUMN_JSON portion and the COLUMN_GET is done in the WHERE section.

Example;

```
SELECT COLUMN_JSON(attr) as 'attribute' FROM items WHERE COLUMN_GET(attr, 'name' AS CHAR) like 'name%' ;
```